# Get number of different chars between two strings allowing a defined number of differences

Tags: c#, char

I want a method that receives as input `two char arrays`, and an integer `d` which represents a max of differences between chars in both arrays and return true or false depending on if arrays are similar differing at most with d chars

so for example

Having

```
char[] a1 = { 's', 't', 'a', 'f', 'f' };
char[] a2 = { 's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k' };
```

and having d=2 would return true because those arrays are almost similar

I was thinking on making a for loop and comparing each char and having a counter of maxDiference and if the counter exceeds return false like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;



namespace auxros
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            char[] a1 = { 's', 't', 'a', 'f', 'f' };
            char[] a2 = { 's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k' };
            bool areDifferent = CharMismatches(a1, a2, 1);
            System.Console.WriteLine("The arrays are diferent at most by one char? " + areDifferent);
            areDifferent = CharMismatches(a1, a2, 2);
            System.Console.WriteLine("The arrays are diferent at most by two chars? " + areDifferent);
            areDifferent = CharMismatches(a1, a2, 3);
            System.Console.WriteLine("The arrays are diferent at most by three chars? " + areDifferent);
        }

        static bool CharMismatches(char[] a1, char[] a2, int d) {
            int mismatches = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
            {
                if (!a1[i].Equals(a2[i]))
                {
                    mismatches++;
                }
                if (mismatches == d)
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }            
            if (mismatches <= d)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;

        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: `if (mismatches <= d){return false;}return true;` This part is redundant, just need `return false;`.

Comment: @cMinor, what should be the behavior when  char[] a1 = {  'k', 'c' ,'a', 't', 's',};char[] a2 = { 's', 't', 'a', 'c', 'k' };, Are you trying to compare char at same index only?

Comment: @Mokchhya it would be interesting it they can be equal, but most case the char arrays would be ordered, however how to add this functionality?

Comment: @cMinor, please see the answer below. I am not sure about the efficiency of the code. :)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it might belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not have `CharMismatches` return the number `d` (up to a max)?

```
static int CharMismatches(char[] a1, char[] a2, int max) 
{
    int mismatches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (!a1[i].Equals(a2[i]))
            if (++mismatches == max)
                return mismatches
    }            
    return mismatches;
}
```

That way, you'll only need to run it once:

```
int max = 3;
int mismatches = CharMismatches(a1, a2, max);
System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
    "The arrays are different at {1} by {0} char", 
    mismatches,
    mismatches == max ? "least" : "most"
));
```

Answer (score 1):

To check for mismatches in the entire array.

```
public class CharCount
{
    public char Char { get; set; }
    public int FirstArrayCount { get; set; }
    public int SecondArrayCount { get; set; }
}

private static int CharMismatches(char[] a1, char[] a2)
{
    var charCountList = new List<CharCount>();

    charCountList.AddRange(a1.GroupBy(a => a).Select(a => new CharCount { Char = a.Key, FirstArrayCount = a.Count() }).ToList());

    charCountList.AddRange(a2.GroupBy(a => a).Select(a => new CharCount { Char = a.Key, SecondArrayCount = a.Count() }).ToList());

    var totalCharCountList= charCountList.GroupBy(a => a.Char).ToDictionary(a => a.Key, b => new CharCount
        {
            Char = b.Key,
            FirstArrayCount = b.Sum(c => c.FirstArrayCount),
            SecondArrayCount = b.Sum(c => c.SecondArrayCount)
        });

    var totalMisMatches= totalCharCountList.Count(a => a.Value.FirstArrayCount == 0 || a.Value.SecondArrayCount==0);
    return totalMisMatches;
}
```